# sed: how to replace text while keeping selected text inside chosen text selection?

Tags: regex, bash, sed

With sed, how would I travel through file(s) and replace something like:

```
alphabet.abc = "123";
```

with

```
alphabet.ABC("123");
```

What I currently have is this:

```
for i in $(ls -a); do sed -i 's/asd/dfg/g' $i; done;
```

But it cannot replace selections while preserving something inside the selection.

Comment: are you trying to change the letters after dot from lowercase to uppercase?

Comment: from something to anything, the conversion from `abc = "123";` to `ABC("123");` was the important part. the answer you added solves that for me and provides a lot of alternative possibilities, so it's good. i just have to wait a second before marking it as correct to make sure i didn't miss anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep the part of the text in  a selected or matched string, you need to use [capturing groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html).AS @anubhava said in his comment, [you don't need to parse the output of `ls` command](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CBwQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmywiki.wooledge.org%2FParsingLs&ei=WCRCVPS1LdaGuASckYCwCg&usg=AFQjCNEbsLAlA5MndgULyIuQVf2hqnAEWg&sig2=CTpKgYOcqRG2vjG6PmTHzw).

```
for i in *; do sed -i 's/\(alphabet\.\)\([a-z]\+\) *= *\([^;]*\);/\1\U\2(\3);/g' $i; done;
```

Example:

```
$ echo 'alphabet.abc = "123";' | sed 's/\(alphabet\.\)\([a-z]\+\) *= *\([^;]*\);/\1\U\2(\3);/g'
alphabet.ABC("123");
```

Through GNU `find` command:

You could run the below command on the directory where the files you want to work with is located.

```
find . -type f -execdir sed -i 's/\(alphabet\.\)\([a-z]\+\) *= *\([^;]*\);/\1\U\2(\3);/g' {} \;
```

Comment: Avoid parsing output from `ls`. Run you loop as `for i in *; do ... done`

Comment: How would you do `for i in *` recursively?